# Why this subquery fails?

Tags: sql, database

```sql
select * 
from 
    (select * from person) as t1; /*ok*/

select * 
from 
    (select * from person) as t1 
where t1.birthday >= '1987-04-09'; /*ok*/

select * 
from 
    (select * from person) as t1 
where 
    t1.birthday = (select max(birthday) from t1); /* fails with 't1 doesn't exist' */
```

I know that the correct SQL for the 3rd query is

```sql
select * 
from person 
where person.birthday = (select max(birthday) from person) /*ok*/
```

Would anyone help me understand why the 3rd SQL query failed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The sql command in the right parentheses (select max(birthday) from t1) is executed first. There t1 is still unknown for the DB engine.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Query Execution Order is:

1. From/Join
2. Where
3. Group By
4. Having
5. Select
6. Distinct
7. Order by

In your case, 'from t1' will be executed first and it will throw an error because t1 hasn't yet been recognised by the DB.

Better use the table name instead of t1.